# How to redirect single URL containing percentage sign?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a 301 redirect for a single URL containing a percentage sign but cannot figure out how to do it

Old URL: http://www.dummydomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/checklflugbl%E4tter.pdf

New URL: https://www.dummydomain.com

So the old (non-existing) PDF should redirect directly to homepage.

I have used following code which works fine for all other PDFs but not for the one with % sign in the URL.

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder1/subfolder2/checklpr%e4senttechnik.pdf /
```

What is the solution for the PDF file containing % in the URL?

Comment: It's not just `%` on it's own it's `%E4` which is a way to encode an a-umlaut (ä).  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/88371

Comment: yes I know that it represents the ä but still can't solve this. I tried the suggestion from the link that you provided but it doesn't work. Unfortunatelly I have no experience with mod_rewrite.

I used the following code but it makes no change: 

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /checklpr%e4senttechnik.pdf/
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dummydomain.com/ [R,L]

Can you help me with the solution?